# Word that describes exploration coupled with transformation?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a verb that combines the sense of explore as well as transforming that which you are exploring? For instance, if I want to describe an explorer who also changed the lands he visited, is there a way to combine that into a single word? The closest I can think of is 'plunder' or perhaps 'raid', but they have negative connotations, and imply taking what isn't yours. I want one that is morally neutral.

The word 'quarry' is close, but again implies taking things. But what I want is more general, that could apply to Johnny Appleseed (who made the world better), but also to a marauder who takes things.

Comment: I thought the whole *point* of exploration was transformation! And to misquote Heisenberg, to observe something is to change it.

Comment: @andy :) Think about a directory structure on your computer. You can explore it (click around the file structure) without changing it. But what is the word for clocking around to explore, and to change the different filenames and such?

Answer (score 3):

Probably **[pioneering](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pioneer)** may fit what you looking for:

- ventures into unknown or unclaimed territory to settle.
- exploration, or settlement into  a new land, region, etc

Comment: Good one! That might be it, I'll have to think on it, it seems so close to 'explore' versus 'transform' and I want the weights to be more equal between the two senses, if that makes sense. That said, pioneer reminds me of some others: 'bore' or 'dig' and synonyms may be even closer: http://thesaurus.com/browse/dig.

Answer (score 1):

From a religious point of view, the purpose of a *mission* or *[missionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionary) activities* is usually to both explore and proselytize at the same time. Famous example is [Dr. Livingston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Livingstone) in Africa.

Comment: Really good one...

Answer (score 0):

**exploitation** covers the second part when used it its positive sense.  It might be weaker on the 'exploration' sense you want to get.